# How to force eclipse to recreate the R (=resources) file?

Tags: android

I just had the odd case that my Android project for some reason would not properly rebuild in Eclipse (v3.5/Galileo). Occasionally that happends and so I did the usual Project => Clean... as I always do in such cases. But this time I now have the odd effect that almost all files show bugs, and looking closer it's that the compiler can't find the R-file (which is indeed missing from the gen subtree).

How do I force eclipse to rebuild that file?

Michael

Comment: I just discovered that there is an error message in the console window:

"W/ResourceType( 8032): Bad XML block: no root element node found"


I guess that's the reason that the R file is not built. Any ideas?

Comment: This error is very uninformative.  I am getting it too, and have no idea what's causing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"W/ResourceType( 8032): Bad XML block: no root element node found" means that you have a malformed XML resource. I think the error message should indicate which file it does not like.

Comment: Solved! I had an icon specified that could not be found. Odd reaction. I have to say, I find the ADT sometimes pretty unforgiving...

Comment: Right - the error can be misleading, you have to look at the *next* line in the console output to find the culprit.  Any sort of issue in your XML resources prevents Eclipse from building the generated classed for you. The tools could be better in this regard.

Comment: @CommonsWare: No!  The error message does NOT indicate which file it does not like.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to force a rebuild by creating an empty R.java file in my gen folder, eclipse then woke up, compiled resources, and replaced my R.java with the correct auto generated one.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, deleting R in order to force a reacreate, however it did not because I forgot to escape an apostrophe

```
<string name="button_go">Let's go!</string>
```

to

```
<string name="button_go">Let\'s go!</string>
```

When R was deleted eclipse showed a tone of errors, making it hard to identify the culprit

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem, and found out it was due to the recent SDK update, which did not automatically include the new "Android SDK Build tools". After i re-launched the SDK Manager, i found the new entry and installed it. After that, it worked perfectly again.